# How to generate DATE from 2 columns to use as selector in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, multiple-columns

I have month and year columns separately in a table, named `m` and `y`.

Now I want to select the records, for example between `2016-08` and `2018-10` (day is not important and that was the reason I have month and year columns)

So I'm looking for a command like below but no success, is there any MySQL function to achieve this?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(`y`,`m`) BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2018-10-01'
```

Comment: I have month and year columns seperately in a table, named "m" and "y".    ... You beter use to a single `DATE` datatype instead of two columns which you need to concat and never will be able to index unless using generated columns off cource..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found the solution myself.

I can extract the date part from two columns by using:

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`m`,'-',`y`,'-01')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
CAST(CONCAT(y, '-', LPAD(m,2,'0'), '-', '01') as DATE)
```

That is create a string representation of a date, YYYY-MM-DD using `CONCAT` and then use `CAST` to convert the string into a date. `LPAD` is used to pad single digit months with a leading 0.